# Process all files without exiting

Tags: perl

I am working on implementing something where i need to check whether value of a variable is defined or not and then proceed with exiting the code. I kept this logic in one script where it has to check for all files opened on my perforce client.

```
 eval { $test = $temp->project($loc); };
    unless ($test){
       print "undefiled value.please check.\n\n";
       exit(1);
     }
```

There are other files which are opened on my perforce client which needs to be validated. Here my script gets exiting when it sees first issue.
Here i want to display all the issues by validating all opened files on my client.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, push your errors into an array, and `die()` after all the checks.

Comment: Could you please share some example?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'd want to change the code to something like this:

```
# Before your loop, set up a variable to store errors
my @errors;

# Where your code is
eval { $test = $temp->project($loc) };

unless ($test) {
  # Don't exit, but store the error and move to the next iteration
  push @errors, "Undefiled value <$loc>. Please check.\n\n";
  next;
}

# After your loop, die id there are any errors
die join "\n", @errors if @errors;
```

**Update:** I like [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)'s suggestion in the comments.

```
# Before your loop, set up a variable to count errors
my $errors;

# Where your code is
eval { $test = $temp->project($loc) };

unless ($test) {
  # Don't exit, but store the error and move to the next iteration
  warn "Undefiled value <$loc>. Please check.\n\n";
  ++$errors;
  next;
}

# After your loop, die id there are any errors
exit(1) if $errors;
```

Comment: Or `my $errors;` + `warn(...); ++$errors; next;` + `exit(1) if $errors;`. More responsive and more crash-resistant.